# Add a comma to a header (php)

Tags: php

I want to comma separate last name and first name in the result. How can I do this? I tried:

```
$headers .= 'From:'.$gender.''.$last_name.','.$first_name.'<'.$email.'>' . "\r\n".
```

but this does not work.

When I use:

```
$headers .= 'From:'.$gender.''.$last_name.''.$first_name.'<'.$email.'>' . "\r\n".
```

it does work, but no comma is added.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Comma is added, https://eval.in/752486. What's the actual usage?

Answer (score 0):

Change the simple quotes to double quotes, so you can get the text as you are searching

```
$headers .= "From: $gender $last_name, $first_name <$email>\r\n";
```

More info:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3446286/5586647

Comment: Why would this make a difference?